# Next js parallel routing ruins all routing when i accept slot as my prop in rootlayout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a slot named @auth inside of an app folder. inside of an @auth folder i have a login folder with page.jsx folder contains this code

```
import LoginPopup from "@/components/Popups/LoginPopup/LoginPopup";

const Login = () => {
  return <LoginPopup />;
};

export default Login;
```

i have this root layout in my app/layout.jsx

```
import Header from "@/components/Header/Header";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer/Footer";
import "./globals.css";

export const metadata = {
  title: "SanSearch",
  description: "Сайт по поиску юридических документов",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children, auth }) {

  return (
    <html lang="ru">
      <body className="font-text" suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
        <Header />
        {children}
        {auth}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

When i try to accept auth slot as a prop and render it with children in my layout my routing gets somehow ruined and get 404 page on every route i try to get. but when i remove auth as my prop everything goes back to normal.
i want to achieve that i can make a contextual modal with parallel routing in next js. i dont want to make an interception route because i dont have a page as popup. only popup that can be achieved by routing on /login page and page behing my popup can still be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not said in next js docs, but i was in need to add a page.jsx and default jsx to all my routes in slot. i added default and page jsx that returned null in @auth and @auth/login and its worked

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48749

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).